# GridBagLayout elements are overlapped in grid Y

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am learning how to use `GridBagLayout` from Java Swing...

In this example I want to put 4 elements in each row as you can see in my code:

```
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        //constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        this.add(label1, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0; 
        
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 0;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        constraints.fill = constraints.BOTH;
        this.add(label, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0; 
        
        JLabel precio = new JLabel();
        precio.setText("Precio    12345.5");
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(precio, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0; 
        
        JLabel cantidad = new JLabel();
        cantidad.setText("Cantidad    ");
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(cantidad, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0; 
        
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
        textfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100 , 30));
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        this.add(textfield, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0; 
        
        JButton boton = new JButton();
        boton.setText("Agregar");
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 4;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(precio, constraints);
        constraints.weighty = 0.0;
```

As you can see in the code.

In the row 0, I want to put a JLabel

In the row 1, I want to put a JLabel with an icon

In the row 2, I want to put a JTextField

In the row 3, I want to put a JTextfield and JTextField on the right
side

And finally in the row 4, I want to put a JButton on the center of
the column.

But I am getting this when I run the JFrame:

[image]

Starting from the second row I am getting the components overlapped, and I don't know why.

Maybe I am missing something from the `GridBagLayout` behaviour because I am still learning how to use it.

Comment: (1-) We can't help because your verbal description of the problem doesn't match the code. In your description you have 2 labels, 3 text fields and a button. In your code you have 4 labels, 1 text field and 1 button. I also don't know why you are using gridwidth/gridheight. Your verbal description doesn't mention anything about this. Post an ascii drawing showing the expected layout of the rows/columns with the component for each row/column. Post a proper [mre]. The first answer shows how to create an MRE. We can then copy/paste/compile/text your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Your code had several syntax errors.  Once I fixed those, I ran your code.

I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted.  Based on your description, I modified your code to produce the following GUI.

[image: Cell 33]

When using a `GridBagLayout`, there are certain parameters you set once, and other parameters you modify for each Swing component.  See the Oracle tutorial [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

Next time, post runnable code that can be copied into an IDE and tested.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cell-33");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 5, 10);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
        panel.add(label1, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        panel.add(label, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        JLabel precio = new JLabel();
        precio.setText("Precio    12345.5");
        panel.add(precio, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        JLabel cantidad = new JLabel("Cantidad");
        panel.add(cantidad, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textfield, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        JButton boton = new JButton();
        boton.setText("Agregar");
        panel.add(boton, constraints);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! the design that i was looking for was in columns, i see that you are putting the components in grix++, but i wanted in gridy++. But with your code i think i can have a better idea to do it :)

Comment: @Luis Bermúdez: The English word for `gridy++` is "rows".

Comment: oh sorry! as you can see, english is not my main language. I will edit my question :)